# Form ViewChild is not getting input field value in component

Tags: angular, validation, viewchild

Code explains the issue. I am not able to use #myForm to access input field validation from controller using ViewChild this.myForm.name

```
        <form role="form" name="myForm" #myForm="ngForm">
           <div>...
             <div>....
               <input #name=ngModel type="text"/>
               <div class="error" *ngIf="!name.valid && (!name.untouched || showErrors)">Please enter a recipient name</div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </form>
```

Now Controller:

```
 export class A imports .... {
      @ViewChild('myForm') myForm;

      private validate() {
        // this.myForm.name is undefined. I don't know why.
        if (this.myForm.name && this.myForm.name.$invalid) {
          return;
        }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Which instance are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 1):

1) You should add ngModel directive to your input and add name attribute, like below.

`<input #name="ngModel" ngModel type="text" name="name" />`

> Why "ngModel"? A directive's exportAs property tells Angular how to
>   link the reference variable to the directive. You set name to ngModel
>   because the ngModel directive's exportAs property happens to be
>   "ngModel".

2) In your component you should use .controls.name instead of .name

```
if (this.myForm.controls.name && this.myForm.controls.name.$invalid) {
   return;
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, great explanation on how Angular links the ref variable using the name attribute. In a template driven form when using `*ngFor` with inputs using `#templateVariable`, form validation (templateVariable.invalid) will work separate on each looped input even though template variable is also looped. This is the method that ensures that still functions. Props, been looking for a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one typo: `#name=ngModel` shall be rather `#name="ngModel"`